# Django NoReverseMatch error when I try to connect to my URL

Tags: python, django

I am getting a NoReverseMatch error when I try to connect to my URL, and I am not sure what the problem is. Thank you for any help. Here is my code:

cart/models.py

```py
from shop.models import Product

class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank = True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Cart'
        ordering = ['date_added']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart_id

class CartItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'CartItem'

    def sub_total(self):
        return self.product.price * self.quantity

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
```

**cart/views.py**

It seems as though the error stems from the add_cart method here, saying that there is no reverse for it.

```
from shop.models import Product
from .models import Cart, CartItem
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

def _cart_id(request):
    cart = request.session.session_key
    if not cart:
        cart = request.session.create()
    return cart


def add_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
                cart_id = _cart_id(request)
            )
        cart.save()
    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
        if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.product.stock:
            cart_item.quantity += 1
            cart_item.save()
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO,
                    'Sorry, no more available!')
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
            product = product,
            quantity = 1,
            cart = cart
        )
        cart_item.save()
    return redirect('cart_detail')

def cart_detail(request, total=0, counter=0, cart_items=0):
    try:
        cart = Cart,objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart)
        for cart_item in cart_items:
            total += (cart_item.product_price * cart_item.quantity)
            counter += cart_item.quantity
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
    return render(request, 'cart.html', dict(cart_items = cart_items, total = total, counter = counter))
```

**cart/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('add/<int:product_id>/', views.add_cart, name='add_cart'),
    path('', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('shop/', include('shop.urls')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls')),
]
```

**Error**
[image]

Comment: Please show the actual error.

Comment: Now you need to show the `shop` view and template, where this error is actually happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem will cause when you're trying to reverse a url without providing required params for your url. There are 2 cases that might cause this issue:

1. You reserve the url for `add_cart` view by using `from django.urls import reverse` (take a look at your shop view):

```py
    # ERROR. It will cause if you're not put any input data on it as your urls defined - missing product_id
    url = reverse('app_name:add_cart')

    # PASS
    url = reverse('app_name:add_cart', kwargs={'product_id': 4})
```

2. On your template of `shop` view, if you use `url` tag:

It also cause this issue if you're not put the product_id into the `url` tag.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'app_name:add_cart' %}">

</form>
```

So it suppose to be:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'app_name:add_cart' product_id=your_product_id %}">

</form>
```

Hope this provided enough information for you to solve the issue